# Why my implemented_function() results in NameError: global name 'Derivative' is not defined?

Tags: python, sympy

Why does this code

```
user_f = lambda a, b: a + b
user_x = lambda u: 2 * u

import sympy
from sympy.abc import t
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import implemented_function
x = implemented_function(sympy.Function('x'), user_x)
f = implemented_function(sympy.Function('f'), user_f)
dx = sympy.diff(f(x(t), t), t, 1)
print(dx)
fl = sympy.lambdify((x(t), t), dx)
print(fl(x(t), t))
```

give me the output below? (Shouldn't it have sufficient information to fully evaluate the derivatives?)

How do I fix (or work around) this error? Assume I am given `user_f` and `user_x` as inputs.

```
Derivative(x(t), t)*Subs(Derivative(f(_xi_1, t), _xi_1), (_xi_1,), (x(t),)) + Subs(Derivative(f(x(t), _xi_2), _xi_2), (_xi_2,), (t,))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <path>, line 12, in <module>
    print(fl(x(t), t))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'Derivative' is not defined
```

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10250

Comment: @cdarke: I actually saw it already, but it's talking about numerical evaluation? I'm doing everything symbolically and I'm not trying to solve any equations.

Comment: Have you tried using the `modules` argument of `sympy.lambdify`: `fl = sympy.lambdify((x(t), t), dx, modules=sympy)`?

Comment: @Leon: I hadn't! That seems to fix it, thank you! Please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing the `modules` argument of `sympy.lambdify()` eliminates the problem:

```
>>> fl = sympy.lambdify((x(t), t), dx, modules=sympy)
>>> print(fl(x(t), t))
Derivative(x(t), t)*Subs(Derivative(_xi_1 + t, _xi_1), (_xi_1,), (x(t),)) + Subs(Derivative(_xi_2 + x(t), _xi_2), (_xi_2,), (t,))
```